# Is there a way to not incur Spells Learn whenever I transform into a Vampire Lord?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I've always been nitpicky about the Statistics page in Skyrim and seeing the Spells Learned stat increase every time I transform into a Vampire Lord sucks. Is there a way to avoid this?